# Height of a wall with several overlapping walls

Tags: c#, revit-api

How do i get the total height of a wall consisting of 4 independent walls?
If i use `BuiltInParameter.WALL_USER_HEIGHT_PARAM`, logically it only gives me the height of a  independent wall.
I already thought about sum, but if you later want, for example, to divide the total height of the wall by two how will the program know to which independent wall that height corresponds.

Thanks for help

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58y7o.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just as you point out, I see no point in trying to condense several different real numbers, possibly completely different, into one single one. It seems to me that you need to make a fundamental decision: are you interested in one single number or several different ones. If you require the different numbers, you will have to decide on how and where to store them. The main two options for storing additional data on a Revit element are adding shared parameters or making use of [extensible storage](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.23). First, make that fundamental choice: yes or no?